# What's the difference between struct { ... } and struct { union { struct { ... } } }?

Tags: c, winapi, struct, unions

Is there a reason why [`DISK_DETECTION_INFO` is defined as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363965.aspx)

```
typedef struct _DISK_DETECTION_INFO {
  DWORD          SizeOfDetectInfo;
  DETECTION_TYPE DetectionType;
  union {
    struct {
      DISK_INT13_INFO    Int13;
      DISK_EX_INT13_INFO ExInt13;
    };
  };
} DISK_DETECTION_INFO, *PDISK_DETECTION_INFO;
```

instead of

```
typedef struct _DISK_DETECTION_INFO {
  DWORD          SizeOfDetectInfo;
  DETECTION_TYPE DetectionType;
  DISK_INT13_INFO    Int13;
  DISK_EX_INT13_INFO ExInt13;
} DISK_DETECTION_INFO, *PDISK_DETECTION_INFO;
```

or am I just overanalyzing this piece of code?

Comment: The union only contains one member, so I think there is no difference.

Comment: are there any implications on alignment?

Comment: I suspect it was a simple mistake by whoever coded up the `DISK_DETECTION_INFO` structure. I'd guess that the `DISK_INT13_INFO` and `DISK_EX_INT13_INFO` structures were meant to be the members of the union, since only one or the other is used.  The only harm caused by the mistake is that it wastes a bit of space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arguably, it's a mistake. However, it's *possible* that we're only given the public definition of the structure. Internally (when used by the Windows kernel), it might be defined as:

```
typedef struct _DISK_DETECTION_INFO {
  DWORD          SizeOfDetectInfo;
  DETECTION_TYPE DetectionType;
  union {
    struct {
      DISK_INT13_INFO    Int13;
      DISK_EX_INT13_INFO ExInt13;
    };
    DISK_INTERNAL_INFO   Private; // Used internally, when DetectionType = -1
  };
} DISK_DETECTION_INFO, *PDISK_DETECTION_INFO;
```

I wouldn't volunteer this as maintainable, safe, or portable, but it's *possible*.

`DISK_INTERNAL_INFO` could even exceed the size of the anonymous `struct` - provided that a user is never instantiating the object themselves the technique might even be considered useful for hiding extra data away from the user but keeping it with the structure. They'd never "see" past the anonymous `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very specific difference between the behaviors: in the first case, neither `Int13` nor `ExtInt13` are initialized when a `DISK_DETECTION_INFO` is initialized.  In the latter case, all four fields are initialized.

MSVC has a slew of quirky extensions, including variable sized arrays at the end of structs, for which the automatic initialization behavior may be undesirable.

EDIT: about "initialization":

Let's say the struct was

```
typedef struct _foo {
  int bar;
  union {
    struct {
      int baz;
      int wee;
    };
  };
} foo;
```

Then, writing `foo x = { 1; }` does not assign a value to baz or wee (they are technically indeterminate).  If the struct was

```
typedef struct _foo {
  int bar;
  int baz;
  int wee;
} foo;
```

Then, writing `foo x = { 1; }` does assign baz=0 and wee=0

Comment: Define "initialized"... If the object is created with a static storage duration I'd expect all fields to be zeroed (in the absence of a constructor) - in all other cases there would be no initialization, regardless of the `union`.

Comment: variable sized arrays at the ends of structs are not msvc specific and there's no such thing here. Anyway, you never initialize one of these, the system returns one to you.

Comment: @David that's from your perspective.  There are developers on the DDK side, and they actually initialize these structs.  The system doesn't magically make these from thin air (although it would be cool if they could)

Comment: Regarding your edit - I'm going to need a link to the standard, since observation says otherwise. I just ran http://codepad.org/LIbVvpUc and http://codepad.org/kMeIUPfS under MSVC and got `1 0 0` for both.

Comment: I think your comments would be better suited to the initialization of ADTs via their constructors - since they occupy the same memory space it is not possible to initialize both implicitly.

Comment: @todda.speot.is does codepad use gcc or msvc?  It's an MSVC extension, and gcc's -fms-extensions isn't 100% compliant with msvc.  nonetheless i will try to find a link

Comment: g++ - but like I said, I tried it under MSVC and I got `1 0 0`

Comment: @todda.speot.is my google-fu is weak, but some searching revealed "Unnamed struct or union members are ignored during initialization."  http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/dynaweb_docs/0650/SGI_Developer/books/CLanguageRef/sgi_html/ch07.html  I remember reading a more thorough discussion in the MSDN documentation years ago, but I have to dig out the old CDs

Answer (score 0):

I think there's reasonable evidence that someone made a simple mistake when they wrote the original `DISK_DETECTION_INFO` struct definition. This mistake escaped into the wild and so it was too late to fix it.

The definition in the header file is:

```
typedef struct _DISK_DETECTION_INFO {
        DWORD SizeOfDetectInfo;
        DETECTION_TYPE DetectionType;
        union {
                struct {

                        //
                        // If DetectionType == DETECTION_INT13 then we have just the Int13
                        // information.
                        //

                        DISK_INT13_INFO Int13;

                        //
                        // If DetectionType == DETECTION_EX_INT13, then we have the
                        // extended int 13 information.
                        //

                        DISK_EX_INT13_INFO ExInt13;     // If DetectionType == DetectExInt13
                } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
        } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
} DISK_DETECTION_INFO, *PDISK_DETECTION_INFO;
```

The documentation reads:

> If DetectionType is DetectInt13, the union is a DISK_INT13_ INFO structure.
>
> If DetectionType is DetectExInt13, the union is a DISK_EX_ INT13_INFO structure.

So it seems very likely that the original intention was for the `DISK_INT13_INFO` and `DISK_EX_INT13_INFO` to be placed in a union since they are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score -4):

Union is usually use to save spaces when a group of fields have mutual exclusive access. That is, when one active, the other must not. As opposed to allocating space for all fields, the space is allocated only for the largest one. The space is used interchangably with other fields. As stated in the link, depending on DetectionType field it's either Int13 or ExInt13 is active. Both use the same allocated space.

Comment: Actually, both Int13 and ExInt13 are within a struct in the OP code, so both have their own address and space.

Comment: @K-ballo: why? the `Int13` and `ExInt13` are in a single struct, therefore they will not overlap.

Comment: @phoxis ...that's why they "have their own address"

Comment: @phoxis: That was exactly my point, I guess I failed to express it correctly? Should have been adresses.

Comment: i misread the comment, sorry for that, we are talking on the same point.

Comment: looks like I miss the inner struct within union, because the usual practice is like my answer. something's wrong with the API design maybe....